# Bouncing (via code and not physics material) and changing height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating on a game where the player is always bouncing up and down can go on different ground with different hights.
I have created this code for bouncing :

```
 transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, Towards.x, Time.deltaTime * 5), minY + Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 3) * maxY) , transform.position.z);
```

with "MaxY" I controll the amount of height in a bounce. I change maxY when the ball is on the ground so it will have a smooth movement

```
        if (Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 3)) < 0.02f && grounded)
        {
            grounded = false;
            maxZ = 2.5f * maxY;
        }
        else if (Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 3)) > 0.02f)
        {
            grounded = true;
        }
```

my problem is when the ball goes to a higher or lower ground.

i detect hight of the ground with this code :

```
            RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit, 40, mask))
        {
            minY = GetComponent<SphereCollider>().radius + hit.point.y;
        }
```

and then it will be added to the minY in next update. but the problem is the player will suddenly change it's position in the air when the minY changes.

I need a code to make this change of height smooth but cant come up with any idea.

Comment: by the way I have tried Mathf.Lerp(minY, holder, Time.deltaTime *2) but it still jumps from one height to another suddenly

Comment: Wait, what is `minY`? A variable? An object?

Comment: minY is the min height that the gameObject can go. since "Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 3)" is between [0, 1] I add it to the height so the min height can be higher.

Comment: I dont recommend you to use lerp, addForce always better for physical interaction.If you want to try different approach to this, I can help i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my very simple solution maybe you can give it a try:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class jump : MonoBehaviour {

    private float radius;
    public float jumpPowa = 350;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        radius = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (isGrounded())
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.up * jumpPowa);
        }
    }

    private bool isGrounded()
    {
        return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, radius + 0, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, thank u good sir! you were right using add force repeatedly is a lot better than using lerp.

Comment: Ah btw u know if update called too fast maybe it can add that force multiple time. You should check that too.Probably you going to see that sometimes it will jump higher than normal thats why.  I hope I could explain what I mean.